# Does a rejected suggested edit affect the reputation of the reviewer?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, reputation

If a user submits a suggested edit, for example from the First Posts or Late Answers, and their edit is not accepted, does that affect their reputation? In what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system does not distinguish suggested edits* made on the Q&A pages from those made within the First Posts / Late Answers review queues. In both cases, an approved edit gives you +2 reputation and a rejected edit doesn't influence your reputation.

<sup>*: I assume that is what you meant, since other review actions can't really be rejected and in any case don't influence your reputation (apart from downvoting answers).</sup>